# How to Update the sql table using datagridview checkbox

Tags: vb.net

I am working on user rights based ristriction on menues and forms.I want to know how to update the table in sql server  from datagridview checkbox 
i have displayed the result  but want to know how to edit table when checkbox is uncheck.
here is the image of my form [image]

here is what i have done till now

```
Private Sub FillGrid()

    Try

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim strSqll As String
        'strSqll = "Select ugr.programid,ugr.Userid,ugr.menuid,mf.menuname,ugr.ChkAdd, ugr.ChkEdit, ugr.ChkDel, ugr.ChkPrint, ugr.ChkView from UserRights ugr inner join menus mf on(mf.menuid=ugr.menuid and mf.programid=ugr.programid) Where ugr.UserID='admin'"
        strSqll = "Select ugr.programid,ugr.Userid,ugr.menuid,mf.menuname, " _
           & "ugr.ChkAdd,ugr.ChkEdit,ugr.ChkDel,ugr.ChkPrint,ugr.ChkView " _
           & "from UserRights ugr inner join menus mf on(mf.menuid=ugr.menuid and mf.programid=ugr.programid) " _
           & "Where ugr.UserID='" & cmbUserName.SelectedValue.ToString() & "'"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSqll, cnMain.dbconnection())
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvUserrights.DataSource = dt
        SettingGridColumns()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub SettingGridColumns()
    dgvUserrights.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dgvUserrights.RowHeadersVisible = False
    dgvUserrights.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dgvUserrights.Columns(1).Visible = False
    dgvUserrights.Columns(2).Visible = False

    dgvUserrights.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Menu "
    dgvUserrights.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Add"
    dgvUserrights.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Edit"
    dgvUserrights.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Del"
    dgvUserrights.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Print"
    dgvUserrights.Columns(8).HeaderText = "View"

    dgvUserrights.Width = Me.Width - dgvUserrights.Left - 20
    dgvUserrights.Columns(3).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.42)
    dgvUserrights.Columns(4).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.11)
    dgvUserrights.Columns(5).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.11)
    dgvUserrights.Columns(6).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.11)
    dgvUserrights.Columns(7).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.11)
    dgvUserrights.Columns(8).Width = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserrights.Width * 0.11)

End Sub
```

please guide me how to edit the record and make changes in table .
Thanks ..

Comment: Try with `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit` methods under GridView.

Comment: @nelek  can u give  and example of code how do i achieve that.

Comment: Would your users edit multiple columns?